# mongoDb 2.6 fails to start on Oracle Linux using the init script

Tags: mongodb

Installed MongoDb 2.6.3 on OL 6.3 using yum, but the default init script seems to fail both when trying to stop and start the mongod service. I could trace the problem with stopping to `$pid_file` being detected as `_/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid` (i.e with a space in front of the path). After that space was removed mongod could be stopped.
However, I cannot seem to start it using the same script (this was the case before the stop-fix too). After issuing the `service mongod start` command, I get `ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1` and in the logs: `ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: Success`, right after the `***** SERVER RESTARTED *****` line, plus an empty pidfile gets created at the quoted location. Nothing else shows up even if I increase the log verbosity. Mongod starts fine if I run it as root, but the above happens if I use an unprivileged user (mongod). I could detect this by executing the command that eventually gets run with and without the user change - `runuser -s /bin/bash mongod -c "ulimit -S -c 0 ; numactl --interleave=all /usr/bin/mongod  -f /etc/mongod.conf"` 
Additional info - I am using the 2.4 configuration format:

```
logpath   = /data/mongodb/log/mongod.log
logappend = true
fork      = true
dbpath    = /data/mongodb/db
auth      = true
port        = 27017
pidfilepath = /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
traceExceptions = true
verbose = true
vvvv = true

keyFile=/data/mongodb/keyfile
```

Checking the permissions on the pidfile path, they seemed okay (rx on the parents, rwx on mongodb). In addition, on another box (same OS) mongoDb 2.4 runs fine. Any idea?

**EDIT** - if I do not use a pidfile (no pidfilepath set), all seems to work fine, but that does not count as a solution, rather a workaround...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to [SERVER-14679 "(CentOS 7/RHEL 7) init.d script should create directory for pid file if it is missing"](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14679), which is fixed for 2.6.5.

In the meantime, please edit the init script according to [this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/50ca596ace0b1390482408f1b19ffb1f9170cab6).

Please add a note to the ticket that it applies to Oracle Linux in case the modified init script starts MongoDB as expected.